# How to remove crease and colour shift between edges?

Tags: rendering, edges

I have these two strips that forms a mobius strip, and I want them to appear seamless. But there's a noticable crease/edge and colour shift between them. How do I stop that. This is because I am going to animate it so that it appears to be getting cut apart, and I don't know how else I could do that without having two separate strips [image]

Comment: To answer X in the [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), make sure the values of normals, color etc. are the same on both sides of each "crease" - edge. The Y problem is perhaps how to create a seamless Mobius Strip, which is by converting a curve to a mesh of a line / narrow rectangle profile (plane / thin cuboid), and then UV unwrapping with one seam (for line/plane profile), and then making sure the flow of the UV is such that the seam is on left/right border aligned with itself, and texture used is seamless.

Comment: Here's the thread of the animation he wants. i'll link it here. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/295529/how-to-make-this-type-of-cutting-and-pulling-apart-animation