# How to make this type of cutting, and pulling apart animation?

Tags: animation

(The gif below is what I am trying to do)

The type of animation I'm trying to do is cutting the mobius strip in half along the center, and then letting it come apart (but the whole thing will still stay as one loop, since it is a mobius strip). The image is what I have right now. I just don't know how to get the ends to pull smoothly apart, as if someone was grabbing the pieces. And I don't know how to have the ends remain joined to each other (the two vertical edges are what I want to remain joined when pull apart).

Also, how do I get that type of outline effect on the planes?

[image]

[image]

Comment: is it possible to provide a blend file with which we can play around?

Comment: linking related questions https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/295483/how-to-remove-crease-and-colour-shift-between-edges