# How to make cutting, and pulling apart animation?

Tags: animation

(The gif below is what I am trying to do)
Someone please help, i've been asking around for days now. This feels like such a simple thing to do.

(some more info)
The type of animation I'm trying to do is cutting the mobius strip in half along the center, and then letting it come apart (but the whole thing will still stay as one loop, since it is a mobius strip). The image is what I have right now. I just don't know how to get the ends to pull smoothly apart, as if someone was grabbing the pieces. And I don't know how to have the ends remain joined to each other (the two vertical edges are what I want to remain joined when pull apart).

Also, how do I get that type of outline effect on the planes?

[image]
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/295529/how-to-make-this-type-of-cutting-and-pulling-apart-animation  Please don't ask the same question twice! If you have more information to add to your original question, edit it and it will be resubmitted and appear again